# How to change layout_gravity in firebase populateView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm developing a chat app using Firebase.
I want to change the layout_gravity of linear layout in row.xml file depending on user's name.

```
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new     FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(
            this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.row, recent
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, ChatMessage chat, int i) {

            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView)).setText(chat.getName());
            ((TextView) [enter image description here][1]view.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView)).setText(chat.getMessage());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView)).setText(chat.getDate());
            Log.e("PopulateView", "Called");
            if (chat.getName().equals(UserName)){

                // Change layout_gravity to right

            }else{

                // Change layout_gravity to left

            }
        }
    };
```

**row.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/out_message_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_chat.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.anand.vishal.uietcommunication.ChatActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:divider="@drawable/chat_divider"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble_gray_new"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/type_a_message"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
set your `layout_width` for the `LinearLayout` in row.xml to `match_parent` and it should work

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.END;
```

Comment: addRule works with RelativeLayout. I tried with RelativeLayout, but it's not working.

Comment: your layout width is set to wrap_content. even if it goes to the right, itll look the same. so i edited the answer again

Comment: Also, consider using `RecyclerView`